# Angular material table data not shown after redirect

Tags: angular

I have a parent component [route: ../register:user_id].

A Material Dialog is used to get search parameters from the user (period and whether the sales for the chosen period are to be shown on individual / daily or monthly basis).

After the search parameters are provided and onSubmit is executed I want to open a child component and show the fetched data therein (there are 3 child components for individual / daily and monthly views).

The first time I execute the search, the data is fetched successfully but not displayed. If the query is run again, **while now already being on the route of the child component** (ex: ../register:user_id/daily), the data is shown as expected.

**Dialog TS**

```
onSubmit(value: any): void {
  //
  //
  //
  this.registerService.emitData({ user_id, shop_id, start_date, end_date } as RegisterQuery);
  this.router.navigate(['register/', user_id, endpoint]);
  this.dialogRef.close();
}
```

Register service

```
observer = new Subject();
public subscriber$ = this.observer.asObservable();

emitData(params) {
  this.observer.next(params);
}
```

**Daily register component**

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.registerService.subscriber$.subscribe(params => {
    console.log('Received', params);
    this.getDailySales(params, 'daily');
  });
}

getDailySales(params, endpoint): void {
  this.registerService.getSales(params, endpoint)
    .subscribe(sales => {
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(sales);
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      console.log(sales);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reference to dataSource remains the same so that material doesn't know that your source changed.

Try this `this.dataSource = [...this.data];`

Or use `BehaviorSubject` like:

```
dataSource = new BehaviorSubject([]);

onAdd($event){
  this.data.push({name: this.currentText});
  console.log(this.data);
  this.dataSource.next(this.data);
}
```